# Webpack causes syntax error in bundle output

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack

I've been struggling for a while now with a problem that I believe is caused by [Webpack](http://webpack.github.io/).

Essentially, I have a Node-based app that I'm bundling up with Webpack to serve to the client (it's a ReactJS based app). The problem occured when I installed the [Tabletop](https://github.com/jsoma/tabletop) NPM package and `require`d it.

When attempting to load the Webpack-created `bundle.js` in the browser, I get a syntax error:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`

which is complaining about this line in `bundle.js`:

`target[capName] = __webpack_require__(387)(""path + '/' + name);`

After some digging, I discover that this line originates from a line in the [Hoek](https://github.com/hapijs/hoek) library (which is a sub-dependency of Tabletop):

`target[capName] = require(path + '/' + name);`

Clearly, Webpack has done something funky here.

I haven't been able to isolate the cause though. Tabletop includes [an example](https://github.com/jsoma/tabletop/tree/master/examples/nodejs) of NodeJS usage which I was able to Webpack and run just fine.

I also cloned Hoek and Webpacke'd it without seeing any illegal transformations like the above.

So now, I'm not sure if this is a Webpack, Hoek, or Tabletop issue, that's why I'm posting it here.

I find no related issues, here or on GH.

All help appreciated!

Comment: It's a dynamic require issue.  Short story webpack by default does not support dynamic requires (eg: require(not + 'a' + fixed + path);) However it is possible to use a plugin to teach it how to handle them. See: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/118 and https://github.com/webpack/webpack/search?q=dynamic+require&type=Issues&utf8=%E2%9C%93

Comment: Since the code is generated by webpack, it's clearly a bug and should be reported on Github. Please also post your config because I assume that it is caused by a specific option.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I agree it's a bug @jhnns, but as shown in the links provided by @generalhenry I'm clearly not the first one to experience this. 
I've realized that Tabletop has an outdated `request` dependency - I'm forking Tabletop to upgrade it and see how that works out. Will post when finished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out an outdated nested dependency of the `hoek` package caused this, due to the dynamic require line shown above. This was removed in hoek@2.0.0.

Unfortunately, Tabletop's `request` dep has an outdated dependency of `hawk` which again depends on `hoek`. I forked `request` and bumped the version, but now I am getting a different error on load in the browser:

`Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "net"`

`net` is a core Node module, so I suspect there is something going on here since we're Webpacking serverside JS to run it in the browser. Nevertheless, that is a different issue so I consider the original question here answered..

But I'm still unable to use Tabletop. I might have to Browserify it and use that bundle directly.

Answer (score 1):

I've used `superagent` with some success when adding

`plugins.push(new webpack.DefinePlugin({ "global.GENTLY": false }));`
and 
`node: {__dirname: true}`

to webpack's config fixes `superagent` for use with webpack.

When using the `request` library, adding the following to webpack's config:

```
node: {
  "net": "empty"
}
```

Fixes `Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "net"`.

However, I'm now having issues with the mime library which is a dependency of `request`: `Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/types/mime.types'`

Aksel, have you had any success fixing `request` with webpack?

Comment: I've touched `mime.types` and `node.types` in `/types/`, but this hardly seems the correct approach.

Comment: Thanks for info. No, I haven't tried yet. I ended up using Tabletop in my Gulpfile instead of in my client app, which avoided the problems related to webpack.

Comment: Came here on a vaguely related issue, `plugins.push(new webpack.DefinePlugin({ "global.GENTLY": false }));` fixed it. Superb!